# Charting large number of series in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet arranged in four columns labeled x1, y1, x2, y2 with 100 rows. Each row represents a line segment starting at x1,y1 and ending at x2,y2. How do I chart these segments in Excel without having to add each series individually? Selecting these columns altogether and inserting chart merely plots them as four series with 100 points or 100 series with four points.

EDIT: is there VBA code that can do this?

Comment: "How do I chart these segments in Excel without having to add each series individually?" You can't, when using only Excel GUI. But this is a programmers O/A site. So what programming language are you able to use? And what have you tried already?

Comment: @AxelRichter Sorry, should've specified, is there a way to do it with VBA? (I'm not very knowledgeable on this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA this is possible.

Let's have following sheet:

[image]

and following VBA code:

```
Sub createChart()

 With ActiveSheet

  Set oChart = .ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Top:=0, Width:=200, Height:=200).Chart
  oChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth

  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For r = 2 To lastRow
   Set oSeries = oChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   oSeries.XValues = Union(.Cells(r, "A"), .Cells(r, "C"))
   oSeries.Values = Union(.Cells(r, "B"), .Cells(r, "D"))
  Next

  oChart.SetElement msoElementLegendNone

 End With

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking to make, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I always say, if you spend five minutes with your data, you can save five hours with your chart. This is one case, where a different data arrangement can yield the desired outcome with much less effort.

Arrange your data as shown below. All X values are in column B and all Y values in column C, with pairs of X,Y values separated by blank rows. Given this data, Excel plots line segments between each pair of X,Y values, and plots a gap corresponding to the blank rows. I've tried to put labels in column A to help explain: Line segments are labeled A, B, etc.

Select the data in columns B and C, and insert an XY scatter chart, with straight lines and no markers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's not a bad approach if I want to exceed Excel's 256 series charting limit, but I think it actually adds considerable time compared to vba to setup and make revisions that way with 100+ sets of formula-based coordinates.